# Rust: conversion between bindgen opaque type and String

Tags: rust, stdstring, rust-bindgen, opaque-types

I want to call c++ code in my Rust code, so I am using bindgen to generate the FFI code. However, I do not know how to convert the String to  string in c++ in my Rust code.

C++ demo code:

```c++
#include <string>

class Foo
{
private:
    std::string m_value;

public:
    Foo();
    std::string get_string_value();
    std::string set_string_value(std::string s);
};

Foo::Foo()
{
    m_value = "test";
};

std::string Foo::get_string_value()
{
    return m_value;
}

std::string Foo::set_string_value(std::string s)
{
    m_value = s;
}
```

build.rs:

```
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        .header("wrapper.hpp")
        .clang_args(&["-x", "c++", "-std=c++11"])
        .allowlist_type("Foo")
        .opaque_type("std::.*")
        .parse_callbacks(Box::new(bindgen::CargoCallbacks))
        .generate()
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");
```

The std_string defined in FFI code is like this:

```
pub type std_string = [u64; 4usize];
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub m_value: std_string,
}
extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "\u{1}_ZN3Foo16get_string_valueB5cxx11Ev"]
    pub fn Foo_get_string_value(this: *mut Foo) -> std_string;
}
extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "\u{1}_ZN3Foo16set_string_valueENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE"]
    pub fn Foo_set_string_value(this: *mut Foo, s: std_string) -> std_string;
}
extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "\u{1}_ZN3FooC1Ev"]
    pub fn Foo_Foo(this: *mut Foo);
}
impl Foo {
    #[inline]
    pub unsafe fn get_string_value(&mut self) -> std_string {
        Foo_get_string_value(self)
    }
    #[inline]
    pub unsafe fn set_string_value(&mut self, s: std_string) -> std_string {
        Foo_set_string_value(self, s)
    }
    #[inline]
    pub unsafe fn new() -> Self {
        let mut __bindgen_tmp = ::std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
        Foo_Foo(__bindgen_tmp.as_mut_ptr());
        __bindgen_tmp.assume_init()
    }
}
```

How can I use `set_string_value()` function in my Rust code? It accepts std_string, but I can not convert the String type to std_string type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `std::string` manipulation code to my `wrapper.cpp` which I use both for generating bindings and for compiling with `cc` to link with the binary. For example:

```cpp
std::string std_string_from_raw_parts(char const* data, size_t len) {
    std::string s (data, len);
    return s;
}
```

and then in Rust code:

```rust
fn std_string_from_raw_parts(s: &'static str) -> bindings::std_string {
    unsafe {
        bindings::std_string_from_raw_parts(s.as_ptr() as *const i8, s.len() as u64)
    }
}
```